# Унарный минус

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема. Создаю класс больших чисел. В общем, я перегружаю оператор -(унарный, меняющий знак). Затем хочу вывести например "`object5+(-object2)`"
Вывожу, но объект2 меняет свой знак навсегда и остаётся таким для следующих выводов и расчётов, а не только в этом выводе. С чем это связано и как это можно исправить?

```
BigInt BigInt::operator -(){
if(!coef.empty()) sign = -1*sign;
return *this;}
```

Comment: наверное, нужно возвращать новый объект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ну а чего вы хотели? вы же сами прописали измени-верни текущий объект `return *this;` создавайте новый объект на основе старого (конструктор копирования) и меняйте у него знак. возвращайте соответственно новый объект...

p.s. ну и не забываем про область видимости и время жизни переменной...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)

Comment: @Андрей это верно только комментарий надо адресовать не @ProkletyiPirat'у а  @Xerocry, а то я явно не смогу принять свой ответ на чужой вопрос:))

Comment: [Сделал](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/2004/)